# Send email after folder changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, filesystems, directory

I'm looking for some advice and help. On Windows Server in ASP.NET C#:

- I have 10 folders (with subfolders and files) associated in a DB to 10 users (columns: `foldername`, `user`).
- I modify the content of the folders, then I press a button and to users with folder changed arrive an alert mail.

I thought to use `FileSystemWatcher`, but this fires automatically for every change (I'm wrong?), and I don't need it.

I think it is more simple to create an "imprint" of every folder and store it in the DB for every user (columns: `foldername`, `user`, `imprint`, `imprint_date`). When I press the button, if the new imprint is different from previous imprint, the system will send an email to the user (and then store the new imprint in the DB).

What do you think about this solution? Can someone can suggest to me how I can create an imprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could traverse the directories and files saving into a file the name + last modified date, and save that as a string.

Whenever you want to check, compare the strings.

You could also simply hash them and see if the hash has changed (which is not 100% accurate since in some end cases you might miss a notification), but should be more than good enough for what you seem to need ...

**Edit:**
As for your comment, no implementation I'm aware of, but it shouldn't be hard to write.

I gave your problem a little though ... You could actually use the `FileSystemWatcher`, but with a twist ... Have a class create 10 watchers, and add their event handlers so they monitor each folder.
When a change fires, in that class, set a bool flag for that user to true (call it `ChangesMade` for example), and unregister the `FileSystemWatcher`. You get no more events fired when more changes are done.

When you hit the send emails buttons, just send emails to whomever have their `ChangesMade` property set to true and register those `FileSystemWatcher` again for those folders.

Comment: Thanks, there is a procedure or a component I can use to create folder/files hash o I must cicle the folder to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, is a goog idea. 10 (or 100 if users increase) watcher are not to heavy for server?

Comment: doubt it. but once they fire, they go to sleep, so not a big issue ...  you can upvote and/or mark as answered if it solved your problem :)